# Notation involving transcendental functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, transcendental-equations

I've seen equations like $\sin^2(x)$ or $\ln^2(x)$, but what does the power do to this? I've tried looking the meaning of this up, but everything I get involves properties of powers that I already know about, such as $2\log(x)\equiv\log(x)^2$.

So what is the difference between say, $\log^2(x)$ and $\log(x)^2$?

Comment: Do you mean $(\log{(x)})^2$ and $\log{(x^2)}$?

Comment: @PeterForeman, No, I did not. I genuinely did not know that $\log^{2}(x)$ was equal to $(\log(x))^2$

Comment: Some people do write that but I strongly suggest not to use the notation $f^n(x) = (f(x))^n$. A standard notation for composition e.g. is $f^n = f \circ \dots \circ f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just a notational convention.

By $\sin^2(x)$, we *mean* $(\sin(x))^2$, but the latter is more cumbersome to write.

The problem with writing $\sin(x)^2$ is that the reader might think it means $\sin(x^2)$.

Similarly, the expression $\log^2(x)$ means $(\log(x))^2$, not $\log(x^2)$.

Comment: Thanks! I've definitely seen $(\sin(x))^2$ before, I just never imagined it would be notated this way. That's definitely much more conventional, so I'll write it that way from now on.

Comment: The problem with $\sin^2(x)$ however is that it could mean $\sin(\sin(x))$. (I'm still ok with the conventional $\sin^2{x}$, though.) Tbh, one should always read $\sin(x)^2$ as $(\sin(x))^2$.

Comment: Unless it's clear from the context that $\sin^2(x)$ is intended as $\sin(\sin(x))$, such intended usage should always be specified so as that the reader is made aware.